# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UserServiceProvider <- UserService <- fbLoginCtrl

Tags: html, angularjs, facebook, authentication, ionic-framework

I have an ionic page with a Facebook login button and a module with a Facebook login controller

the controller is

```
    module.controller('fbLoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $q, UserService, $ionicLoading) {
    // This is the success callback from the login method
    var fbLoginSuccess = function(response) {
        if (!response.authResponse){
            fbLoginError("Cannot find the authResponse");
            return;
        }

        var authResponse = response.authResponse;

        getFacebookProfileInfo(authResponse)
        .then(function(profileInfo) {
            // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
            UserService.setUser({
                authResponse: authResponse,
                userID: profileInfo.id,
                name: profileInfo.name,
                email: profileInfo.email,
                picture : "http://graph.facebook.com/" + authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
            });
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $state.go('app.home');
        }, function(fail){
            // Fail get profile info
            console.log('profile info fail', fail);
        });
    };

    // This is the fail callback from the login method
    var fbLoginError = function(error){
        console.log('fbLoginError', error);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    };

    // This method is to get the user profile info from the facebook api
    var getFacebookProfileInfo = function (authResponse) {
        var info = $q.defer();

        facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=email,name&access_token=' + authResponse.accessToken, null,
          function (response) {
              console.log(response);
              info.resolve(response);
          },
          function (response) {
              console.log(response);
              info.reject(response);
          }
        );
        return info.promise;
    };

    //This method is executed when the user press the "Login with facebook" button
    $scope.facebookSignIn = function() {
        facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(success){
            if(success.status === 'connected'){
                // The user is logged in and has authenticated your app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed request, and the time the access token
                // and signed request each expire
                console.log('getLoginStatus', success.status);

                // Check if we have our user saved
                var user = UserService.getUser('facebook');

                if(!user.userID){
                    getFacebookProfileInfo(success.authResponse)
                    .then(function(profileInfo) {
                        // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
                        UserService.setUser({
                            authResponse: success.authResponse,
                            userID: profileInfo.id,
                            name: profileInfo.name,
                            email: profileInfo.email,
                            picture : "http://graph.facebook.com/" + success.authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
                        });

                        $state.go('app.home');
                    }, function(fail){
                        // Fail get profile info
                        console.log('profile info fail', fail);
                    });
                }else{
                    $state.go('app.home');
                }
            } else {
                // If (success.status === 'not_authorized') the user is logged in to Facebook,
                // but has not authenticated your app
                // Else the person is not logged into Facebook,
                // so we're not sure if they are logged into this app or not.

                console.log('getLoginStatus', success.status);

                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: 'Logging in...'
                });

                // Ask the permissions you need. You can learn more about
                // FB permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4
                facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email', 'public_profile'], fbLoginSuccess, fbLoginError);
            }
        });
    };
})
```

and my Index page button is

```
   <div class="button-bar" ng-controller="fbLoginCtrl">
       <button class="button button-positive icon icon-left ion-social-facebook waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="facebookSignIn()">Facebook</button>
   </div>
```

When i  try to run it in the emulator i get this error 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UserServiceProvider <- UserService <- fbLoginCtrl

and i don't know how to solve the problem or what is even causing it
please someone help me with this issue

Comment: Usually this kind of error occurs when the dependency you are injecting is not defined or its not properly injected.

Comment: @MuhammedNeswine I know that's maybe the problem but i don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are not getting the `facebookConnectPlugin` plugin. Try running a `bower install` or `npm install` before running the emulator.

And if you haven't installed it yet, visit http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/ for the instructions

Comment: I followed the guide but i think it's old cause i keep getting error while installing like directory not found or error at `--target android-19`

can you please guide where i can find a full tutorial on how to implement Facebook authentication in an ionic app ? 
Thanks for your help